# ASP Ajax control toolkit calender extender not displayed properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

ASP Ajax control toolkit Calender extender is not appearing properly. Only text values are appearing and looks like CSS is not applied. I tried to disable all the CSS definitions for the page but still it is not being displayed properly.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeBehind="DataDownload.aspx.cs" Inherits="myapp.DataDownload" %>


    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

    <asp:Content ID="head_content" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="body_content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" CssClass="inp-form" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calFromDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFromDate" >
     </asp:CalendarExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting Existing Js files on page.

reason : simple, As we know ajax on [page load complete] method makes javascript Code on the fly , which conflicts with existing javascript/jquery on the page, which  results on malfunction of either functionality.

Comment: Not only JS files I commented all my css files. Because I thought it was because of CSS problem. Still it did not work. Now I am using javascript based HTML editors.

Comment: about jquery related files and also ,can i get access url so i can test in firebug for the same